# adding deltatime to each date in loop python

Tags: python, datetime

hey guys I was trying to add time delta to each date in loop range of days but it end up adding only the time delta only to the first date in the loop the code is as follows:

```
import datatime
import time
from datetime import timedelta, date


td= datetime.timedelta(days=7)

for d in daterange(date(2019, 1, 1,), date(2019, 1, 5)):
   print(d+td)


>>>2019-01-08
>>>2019-01-09
>>>2019-01-10
>>>2019-01-11
```

why the adding was not applied to dates in the range and what is the solution ?

Comment: You aren't importing anything called `daterange`; this code can't work.

Comment: Aside from that, this seems to be working fine. 2019-01-01 + 7 days = 2019-01-08; 2019-01-02 + 7 days = 2019-01-09 ...

Comment: it is working but the problem is with adding the time delta to all outputs not just to the first one

Comment: It's doing exactly that. You're iterating over 4 days and adding one week to each of them.

Comment: I need the outputs to be added with 7 days not only the first output, as follows:2019-01-08, 2019-01-15, 2019-01-22, 2019-01-29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's hard to tell what's wrong with your original code, are you maybe looking for something like this, to iterate over dates/datetimes using a given step?

```
import datetime


def date_range(start, end, step: datetime.timedelta):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += step


for d in date_range(
    start=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
    end=datetime.date(2019, 2, 9),
    step=datetime.timedelta(days=7),
):
    print(d)
```

outputs

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-08
2019-01-15
2019-01-22
2019-01-29
2019-02-05
```